# Is my engine missing a bolt?

Tags: engine

[image]Civic coupe vti 1999.

Engine is b16a2.

I notice there engine has a hole for what seems to be a stud.  Couldn’t get my head positioned to see if it goes into the engine.

I have taken a picture from behind.

Does it look like there’s meant to be something going into this, is the hole letting air into the engine or what is it exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: it is one of the lifting points on the engine block,you will find one on the oposite side of your engine block too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bent piece of wire to check if it is a blind hole. It will be, otherwise you would see oil, water etc coming out...

Part if the standard holes provided during manufacture for various options...